# Passing the value of input$variable as an argument in Rshiny to external script call

Tags: python, r, shiny

R shiny code being used is:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)
ui <-  fluidPage(
  headerPanel( list(tags$head(tags$style("body {background-color: #F4F6F6 ; }")))),
  titlePanel("RADP CR Prediction Tool"),
  br(),
  tags$head(tags$script(src = "message-handler.js")),
  textInput('Region', label = 'Enter the region'),
  textInput('Regulatory', label = 'Enter the regulatory status'),
  textInput('Description', label = 'Enter the description for the CR'),
  br(),
  br(),
  actionButton("goButton", "Go!"),
  mainPanel(textOutput('region'),textOutput('description')),
  bsModal("modalExample", "Your summary", "goButton", size = "large",dataTableOutput("data_summary"))
     )

server <- function(input,output,session) {
  #observe the add click and perform a reactive expression
  observeEvent( input$goButton,{
    x <- input$Region
    y <- input$Regulatory
    z<- input$Description
    print (x)
    system("/Users/ravinderbhatia/anaconda/bin/python /Users/ravinderbhatia/Downloads/Untitled3.py input[[x]] ,'y', 'z'")
    MyData <- read.csv(file="/Users/ravinderbhatia/Downloads/data.csv", header=TRUE)
    #reactive expression
    output$region <- renderPrint(x)
    output$description <-renderPrint(y)
    output$data_summary <- renderDataTable({
      MyData
    })
  }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Issue is in the follwing line:

```
 system("/Users/ravinderbhatia/anaconda/bin/python /Users/ravinderbhatia/Downloads/Untitled3.py x,y,z")
```

How to pass the actual value of region in the system call. Here print(x) works fine, but when I pass x as a argument, I want to pass the value stored inside it.(input$region)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, like that you are just passing a character x to the system, and it probably has no idea what to do with that.

What if you changed this line:

```
system("/Users/ravinderbhatia/anaconda/bin/python /Users/ravinderbhatia/Downloads/Untitled3.py input[[x]] ,'y', 'z'")
```

to:

```
system(paste("/Users/ravinderbhatia/anaconda/bin/python /Users/ravinderbhatia/Downloads/Untitled3.py", x, y, z))
```

just try out those few lines, where i replaced "system" with "print"

```
x= "desc"
y= "region"
z= "etc"
print("/Users/ravinderbhatia/anaconda/bin/python /Users/ravinderbhatia/Downloads/Untitled3.py input[[x]] ,'y', 'z'")
print(paste("/Users/ravinderbhatia/anaconda/bin/python /Users/ravinderbhatia/Downloads/Untitled3.py", x, y, z))
```

Comment: I have already tried passing x, y, z. That does not work. Python takes its x as an argument, not the value in it.

Comment: What if you save the command in a variable and pass it then to system().  Like: a <- paste("/Users/ravinderbhatia/anaconda/bin/python /Users/ravinderbhatia/Downloads/Untitled3.py", x, y, z)  
system(a)

Comment: No success. Still it reads x,y,z only. Also not sure about the comas in between x,y and z.

Comment: I tried to create a reproducible example and it works for me. It takes the values, that are assigned to x,y,z. I just changed the first part of the system-command to the full path of the python.exe. (system(paste("C:/Anaconda/python.exe C:/py_function.py", x, y, z))), as you are only pointing to python and not an executable ?

Comment: I am on Mac. Do not have executable.

Comment: Hm, what is the error msg? Is it saying, that it doesnt find x,y,z?  If you paste the arguments together, there are no commas left, so that should be fine.  You could also use the collapse argument of paste like this: paste("/Users/ravinderbhatia/anaconda/bin/python /Users/ravinderbhatia/Downloads/Untitled3.py", x, y, z, collapse = " "). It will put a white space between every argument given to paste.